# MySQL: Can I use INNER JOIN to find Items of a table belonging to a category defined in a second table?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables **imc_shop** and **imc_shop_category**.
The **imc_shop_category** reflects the categories a certain item of the shop belongs to.

In my example the shop table has two items with id 10 and 11.
In the category table item 10 points to category 3, 11, 16, 19 and 31
where item 11 points to 31, 3, 12, 16 and 19.

If I search for items, which belong to **category 3 and 12** only item **11** should be returned.

I tried the following query, which did not work:

```
SELECT s.* FROM imc_shop AS s
 INNER JOIN imc_shop_category AS c ON s.itemId = c.itemId
 WHERE c.categoryId = 3 AND c.categoryId = 12
```

[image: Tables and content]

Any idea how to get the correct result?

Comment: Please: Use text, not images/links, for what can be given as text. For code questions give a [mre]. Show what you are able to do. Research--This is a faq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.* FROM imc_shop AS s
 INNER JOIN imc_shop_category AS c ON s.itemId = c.itemId
 AND (c.categoryId = 3 OR c.categoryId = 12)
GROUP BY s.itemID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.categoryId) = 2
```

Comment: Great! It worked well. Thanks a lot!
But I replaced AND with WHERE in line 3, even if also AND worked. I've actually not yet seen AND at this position.

But now I got the next problem.
How can I count the number of hits?
COUNT(s.itemId) gives me the wrong results.